# Variations of Hodge structures of Calabi-Yau threefolds

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, hodge-theory

It is a question about R. Bryant and P. Griffiths's paper Some observations on the Infinitesimal Period Relations for Regular Threefolds with Trivial Canonical Bundle. I am going to use the language in this paper. Suppose $X_s,\,s\in S$ is a family of Calabi-Yau threefolds with Hodge number $h^{2,1}=m$ parameterized by an $m$ dimensional complex manifold $S$. From section 2, there is a polarized Hodge structures $(H_{\mathbb{Z}}, H^{p,q},Q)$ of weight 3 for each fiber $s \in S$, where $H_{\mathbb{Z}}$ is the homology of fiber, $Q$ is a non-degenerating bilinear form
\begin{equation}
Q:H_{\mathbb{Z}} \otimes H_{\mathbb{Z}} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}
\end{equation} 
$H^{p,q}$ is the Hodge decomposition of $H=H_{\mathbb{Z}} \otimes \mathbb{C}$, thus we have 
\begin{equation}
h^{3,0}=h^{0,3}=1, h^{2,1}=h^{1,2}=m
\end{equation}
and 
\begin{equation}
H=H^{3,0} \oplus H^{2,1} \oplus H^{1,2} \oplus H^{0,3}\\
H^{p,q}=\bar{H^{q,p}}
\end{equation}
with corresponding Hodge filtration
\begin{equation}
0 \subset F^3 \subset F^2 \subset F^1 \subset F^0 =H
\end{equation}
where $F^p=\oplus_{k \geq 0}H^{p+k,3-p-k}$.

Since $h^{3,0}=1$, suppose $F^{3}(s)=H^{3,0}(s)$ is spanned by the period $z(s)$, then from section 2, variation of Hodge Structure Associated to Certain 3-Folds, we have 
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial z(s)}{\partial s^i} \in F^2(s), \, i=1,\cdots, m
\end{equation}
and 
\begin{equation}
F^2(s)= \text{span}\{z(s), \frac{\partial z(s)}{\partial s^1}, \cdots, \frac{\partial z(s)}{\partial s^m} \}
\end{equation}
i.e.

\begin{equation}
\text{dim}~~ \text{span}\{z(s), \frac{\partial z(s)}{\partial s^1}, \cdots, \frac{\partial z(s)}{\partial s^m} \}=m+1
\end{equation}
My question is that could it be extended to the case 
\begin{equation}
F^1(s)= \text{span}\{z(s), \frac{\partial z(s)}{\partial s^i}, \frac{\partial^2 z(s)}{\partial s^i \partial s^j}  \} \\
F^0(s)= \text{span}\{z(s), \frac{\partial z(s)}{\partial s^i}, \frac{\partial^2 z(s)}{\partial s^i \partial s^j},  \frac{\partial^3 z(s)}{\partial s^i \partial s^j \partial s^k} \}
\end{equation}

If it fails in $F^0$ and $F^1$, why?

If $m=1$, does there exist method to find when $\{z(s), \frac{\partial z(s)}{\partial s^i}, \frac{\partial^2 z(s)}{\partial s^2},  \frac{\partial^3 z(s)}{\partial s^3} \}$ is linearly independent?